# True and False return of functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to display the message “Yes” or “No” for getting a function return of true or false respectively (not directly changing the word true and false)
Display but not using alert.

How can I do that? Thanks.

```
function myFunction {
  if (Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 0) return false
  else return true;
}
```

Comment: alert(myFunction()? 'yes' : 'no')

Comment: @RenaldoBalaj I just want to display the messages out in the page instead of using alert. Any methods? Thanks

Comment: document.write(myFunction()? 'yes' : 'no');

Comment: he was using alert just as an example, but you can use the code inside the alert for anything

Comment: @AzizStark How about displaying on the same page? Not in a new tab.

Comment: Create a <h1 id="demo"> </h1> tag and add document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction()? 'yes' : 'no'; in your script.

Comment: You can simplify the function because `==` already gives `true` or `false`: `return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0;`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (myFunction()) { console.log("Yes"); }
else { console.log("No"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are new, so welcome :v --

Way 1: `document.write(myFunction()? 'yes' : 'no');`

Way2:

```
<p id="demo" ></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()"> yes or no </button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction()? 'yes' : 'no';
}
</script>
```